# API to insert data to array of objects in mongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I am trying to insert array of objects inside array of objects in my mongoDB schema. This is how i want my schema to appear.

```
const CourseSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    categoryname: {
        type: String,
        required: "Course Category",
        min: 3,
        max: 100
    },
    coursename: {
        type: String,
        required: "Course Name",
        min: 3,
        max: 100
    },
    levels:
        [
            {
                levelid: Number,
                levelname: String,
                chapter:
                    [
                        {
                            chapternumber: Number,
                            chaptername: String,
                            content: String  //To be elaborated
                        }
                    ]
            }
        ]
});
```

My API which i have written looks like this:

```
exports.addcourse = (req, res) => {
    let levels = [];
    levels.push({
        levelid: req.body.levelid,
        levelname: req.body.levelname,
        chapter: [
            {
                chapternumber: req.body.chapternumber,
                chaptername: req.body.chaptername,
                content: req.body.content
            }
        ]
    })
    const newCourse = new Course({
        coursename: req.body.coursename,
        categoryname: req.body.categoryname,
        levels: levels
    });
    newCourse.save(function (error) {
        if (error) res.json({ message: 'could not add course because ' + error });
        res.json({ newCourse: newCourse });
    });
}
```

This works fine when i enter one level and one chapter, but gives an error when i enter multiple data.
I am giving input from postman 'x-www'form-urlencoded'.

please help.

The error i get when i add one more levelid and levelname in postman

```
{
    "message": "could not add course because ValidationError: levels.0.levelid: Cast to Number failed for value \"[ '1', '2' ]\" at path \"levelid\", levels.0.levelname: Cast to String failed for value \"[ 'First Level', 'Second Level' ]\" at path \"levelname\""
}
```

The data i am trying to enter
[image: The data i am trying to enter[1]]

Comment: What is the error that you are getting? Also please share the data on which you are getting the error.

Comment: This is the error i get when i try to add one more levelid and levelname,                         {
    "message": "could not add course because ValidationError: levels.0.levelid: Cast to Number failed for value \"[ '1', '2' ]\" at path \"levelid\", levels.0.levelname: Cast to String failed for value \"[ 'First Level', 'Second Level' ]\" at path \"levelname\""
}

Comment: I think something's not right in the data that you are trying to insert, can you please share the data once?

Comment: yeah i edited my question to add a screenshot of my postman

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In postman, when you are sending the same key **levelid** twice, it converts it to array containing both the values. Like in your case, in **req.body.levelid**, you will receive [1, 2]. But in your schema, **levelid** is expecting a number value. Also, you are reading it wrong in your API code. Instead of getting **levelid** and **chapter** seperately, you can get the **levels** array in request body with values **levelid**, **levelname** and **chapter**. Similarly, **chapter** can be an array of objects. **req.body.levels** will look like this:

```
[{
  levelid: 1,
  levelname: "level1",
  chapter: [{
              chapternumber: 1,
              chaptername: "chapter1",
              content: "chapter1-content"
           }, {
              chapternumber: 2,
              chaptername: "chapter2",
              content: "chapter2-content"
           }] 
}]
```

Try this in postman by giving input in **raw**

Comment: Yeah giving input using Raw works great, but why not using the form-encoded.?

Comment: I tried using couple of for loops to but its giving output in a weird way.    
    for (let i = 0; i < (req.body.levelid).length; i++) {
        for (let j = 0; j < (req.body.chapternumber).length; j++) {
            levels.push({
                levelid: req.body.levelid[i],
                levelname: req.body.levelname[i],
                chapter: [{
                        chapternumber: req.body.chapternumber[j],
                        chaptername: req.body.chaptername[j],
                        content: req.body.content[j]
                    }]})}}

Comment: Because the form-encoded in postman is not sending the desired body and that's why mongo is sending an error on insertion. 
If I am not wrong, each chapter array with values chapternumber, chaptername etc is associated with specific levelid and levelname and sending the values loosely like you are doing is not a correct way to do it. Rather than getting these values seperately, try getting "levels" array in request body as I have mentioned, and it will work fine.